# What is this adjustable/foldable rack for?

Tags: furniture, hand-tools, tool-identification, hardware-identification

I inherited this whimsical object along with several other woodworking tools.

[image]

The item resembles a stepladder, albeit a very small one (about 50cm). A hinge is connecting the two main sides - one being some sort of rack and the other a slightly thinner solid board. The third side is probably a ratchet gear rack, although when the object is oriented the way it is in the photo, the ratchet gear rack is pulled down and away from the pawl, negating the functionality. The item is fully made of wood and not more than 80 years old.

If you cannot see the image, try to view it in my Google Photos:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/RvfapfBEemiYu8kL9

Comment: I got nothing, except a complete guess that it's for bending something. Did you try a reverse image search/Google Lens?

Comment: It looks like something I SHOULD recognize, but I'm not coming up with anything

Comment: @Graphus, that's a Good idea! I tried now, and it shows a mix of mostly wooden sleds, wine racks, armchair rests, and rocking horses, but none of them have the ratchet gear rack.

Comment: You say _"...although when the object is oriented the way it is in the photo, the ratchet gear rack is pulled down and away from the pawl..."_ Is the orientation where the pawl makes sense such that the "runners" are along the ground and the flat board angled across the top?

Comment: @gnicko In the position you describe: "...'runners' are along the ground and the flat board angled across the top?" there would have to be something pushing the angled board upwards. Perhaps some compressible cargo jammed into the triangular opening between them.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Yeah. From the angle of the teeth on the ratchet and the angle of the handle, it looks almost like you're supposed to pull the "ratchet stick" to release the pressure.... from whichever side of this thing is the _business end_.